# What is the term for a cat who is bossing other cats around?

Tags: terminology

In a multicat house, there is often a cat who is the boss for other cats. What is the proper  term for such cat? Is it "dominant cat"? Are there any other, less formal, terms for it?

Comment: Lion King? (In its own mind, at least)

Comment: 'She Who Must Be Obeyed'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The traditional term would be Alpha Male/Female, but I also like Top Cat and Boss Cat.

Comment: I like Boss Cat for colloquial use, and Alpha (or Alpha Male/Female) for more formal usage.